# can't get src from object vue.js vite

Tags: image, vue.js, src, vite

Hi guys now I am building a quiz app in which you should find the English version of a word by seeing an image and description under the image

My data.js file is like this.
`export const Quizzes = [`
`{ firstWord: "happy", secondWord: "srećan", imageSrc: "happy--women.jpg", },`
`{ firstWord: "lijepo", secondWord: "nice", imageSrc: "nice-women.jpg" },`
`]`
and I am importing it into my component like this
`import { Quizzes } from "../data";`
and binding it to a variable like
`data() {`
 `return {`
 `quizItems: Quizzes,`
`};` 
`},`
and using it in my tags like
`<img class="quiz-image":src="'../assets/' + quizItems[currentCount].imageSrc"alt="Quiz Image"/>`
`<p class="quiz-word">{{ quizItems[currentCount].firstWord }}</p>`
in this case quizItems[currentCount].firstWord is working but img biding is not working in this case the browser gives me an error like `happy--women.jpg:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:5173/assets/happy--women.jpg 404 (Not Found)` please can someone help me in this case